# change the menu font size

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on this website http://blackbottle.com.au/

I really want to change the menu font size to be just a bit larger. I have tried using every class combination naming the menu items to change the font! The only thing I can think of now is in-line CSS but you can't do that on these menu items. Does anyone have a work-around or another way to change the menu font size?

Comment: your question is different from the text of the question. Can you please be lil more specific. Thanks

Comment: The `<hr>` tag does not use a closing slash.

Comment: @Rob it does in [XHTML](http://www.xstandard.com/en/articles/xhtml-reference/hr/) ;)

Comment: @TripleDeal She's not using XHTML.

Comment: @Rob Neither does her website use `<hr>`. I couldn't even find a `<hr>` element on her homepage. Anyway, maybe see prefers to use the slash? One rather has his CSS external and the other rather has it internal...

Comment: @TripleDeal It's in her title. The closing slash is not specified for the `<hr>` tag in any HTML spec so it's pointless and useless and only takes up space.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! It is on my menu page. I accidentally mixed up my question name with the question I accidentally asked.... Oops. But I would like to know how to change the <hr> tag if possible :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this class for your links.

```
a.nav-link {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this in your style.css file:

```
.main-navigation a {
    color: #fcfbf9;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.8rem; // This needs to be changed
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

or override it with another css file

And could you explain to me what you want to change of the `<hr>` element? Because your title is completely different compared to the content of your question.

Comment: Apologies I totally mixed up my question name and the actual question I aksed with a different one! But the navigation size was more important so thanks for answering. I didn't realize the a needed to be at the end of the class name but this finally did the trick!!! Thank you sooo much! 

I just wanted to change the <hr> element to be a different color. It looks like it's a very thin yellow now and I want to change it to #f68c7f

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the font size of the menu items by altering the font-size for class .main-navigation a

```
.main-navigation a {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

CSS always reads the last entry as the main one. So in the above example, CSS will read the font-size as 1rem. If the browser does not support rem, only in that case it will read the font-size as 13px. In short, whatever is written last, overrides what is written before it.

I hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: YES! This worked! :D I was missing the "a {" at the end of the class. and then I've nevered used 1rem; before but I love that. 

And thanks for the explanation this really helped me learn. Thank you! :)